# Cloudant/Db2 - How to determine if a database table row was read from?

Tags: db2, cloudant

I have two databases - `Cloudant` and `IBM Db2`. I have a table in each of these databases that hold static data that is **only read from and never updated**. These were created a long time ago and I'm not sure if they are used today so I wish to do a clean-up.

I want to determine if these tables or rows from these tables, are still being read from.

Is there a way to record the read timestamp (or at least know if it is simply accessed like a dirty bit) on a row of the table when it is read from?

OR

Record the read timestamp of the entire table (if any record from it is accessed)?

Comment: In terms of Cloudant, every read access will be recorded in the http access logs.

Answer (score 0):

There is [SYSCAT.TABLES](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=views-syscattables).LASTUSED system catalog column in Db2 for DML statements on whole table.
There is no way to track each table row read access.

Comment: since SELECT statements are not considered as DML, this will not help. My tables are only read from, not written to.

Comment: SELECT **is** considered as DML. [stmt_type_id](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=reference-s#r0056450)

Comment: A purely SELECT might not be DML - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5634/does-the-select-statement-count-into-dml. I will give this a try and check if it works for pure SELECT queries.